# Is there any way to scrape the commands from this page using Python?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

I've used beautifulsoup to do some basic scraping of text, but for this page (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart.html), the text in question is formatted as an image. One can click on each individual command (e.g. BarChart[{1, 2, 3}]) to copy it and manually paste it, but I was wondering if there was a reasonable way I could get all 143 commands without doing so for each individual piece of code.

Comment: Is there any way? Yes there is.

Comment: Look at the scripts the page loads, find and understand `load_copy_text()` which is invoked for each such click. Maybe scraping is not even needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this might be an overkill, but you can use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), basically automating the action of mouse click and use the **clipboard** package to get the copied text back into Python. A rough idea will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import clipboard

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart.html")

#get all the image elements
elem: = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")

#click and paste
text_list = []
for elem in elems:
    #clicking on the image element
    elem.click()

    #get text from clipboard
    text = clipboard.paste()

    #check if text is empty
    if text != "":
        text_list.append(text)
```

As I said, this is probably not the best way to do it, you can look into the `clipboard.js` file on the website to check whether there's an easy way out. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you watch your browser's dev tools when interacting with the page, you'll see that hovering over one of those image/text elements makes a request to load the text of that element. So you'll have to make one request per text to get all of those values. The urls all look something like this: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Files/BarChart.en/i_5.txt.

So first, you should find a way generate all of these requests. It looks like they're all odd values (`i_1.txt`, `i_3.txt`, etc) and they correspond with a `div`'s id.

These don't give you great looking text though, it's got a lot of markup and the text is escaped:

```
<pre name='i_5_in' id='i_5_in' class='IFT'>
  BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {5, 2}}, 
  ChartLabels -&gt; {&quot;a&quot;, &quot;b&quot;, &quot;c&quot;}]
</pre><div class='IFU'>
<a name='408182431'></a>http://wolfram.com/xid/0cq0nbvj-g1a1u5</div>
```

As a couple people have pointed out, `clipboard.js` is where the javascript that initiates and processing these requests can be found. You could get there either by checking the element's event listeners or by tracing through the request's initiator stack. This has some lines you can use to write up a Python function that will scrape them. There's a library called PyQuery ([docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery)) that lets you use jQuery-like selectors on HTML that could speed this up.